# searchble select input react js

Tags: reactjs

hi i have problem with react js  TextField Component when i add select to it dose not allow typing so to allow typing i have to set the select to false but that will not open the dropdown that include the options

```
const {searchtext, setsearchtext} = useState('')

<TextField
  id="outlined-select-currency"
  select
  label="Select"
  defaultValue="EUR"
  value={searchtext}
  helperText="Please select your currency"
  onKeyDown={e => {
    setsearchtext(searchtext + e.key.toString()
  }}
>
  {currencies.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

i have tried keydown event
i want to be searchable

Comment: Is this `TextField` part of a specific library of components?  Which one?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is MUI's `Autocomplete` component.
Check MUI's Official [Documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/)